# Azure logging API sample

Tags: c#, azure-log-analytics

I have tried the C# sample at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api butI always get an error response back. Has anyone been able to get this sample to work? I have double and triply checked the workstation id and the secret key but still cannot call the API sucessfully.

Comment: Could you display the error you got? So we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Doris Lv mentioned, displaying the error would certainly help to understand the issue better.

In additional to it what I could observe in general is, the C# example provided for the Azure Monitor Data Collector API uses ASCII encoding while other parts of the page reference UTF8 so try to tweak your code with UTF8 and see if it resolves your error.